# Easy way (minimal development) way to expose Java API via REST

Tags: java, rest

Assume that one has a POJO library, which has a Java API that can be used to create POJO or Enterprise Java applications. If I wish to expose that API, or a subset of it, as RESTful API -- and do so with minimal development effort, what would be my options ?

Of course, while exposing the RESTful API, I would like to ensure things like security, usage quotas etc. are taken care of.

Comment: That's out of scope for the forum. [Please see How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [On Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and also [Questions to Avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: For simplicity and minimal amount of code, [JAX-RS](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/) is the way to go.

Comment: http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/ as a variant of creating micro services with rest

Comment: Thanks VGR and Ishikawa.

Comment: You can have a look at the [Spark](http://sparkjava.com) framework. Then there's [Play](https://www.playframework.com) framework too, but it has a learning curve to it. Go with Spark. Its easy to setup and use.

Comment: You could also use Restlet - see http://restlet.com/products/restlet-framework/ and http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/tutorials/2.3.

Comment: Try http://www.takes.org/

Comment: Thanks folks. All of the frameworks have some learning curve, even though they look quite promising otherwise. Looking for something simpler.

Comment: After some more thorough review, Spark and Play look very promising.